# swiftのswitch文について質問です。

Tags: swift

ある解説書で

```
let dataPoint = (2014, 12, 28)
switch dataPoint {
case (_, 8, let date) :
        println("In summer vacation. remind days: \(30 - date)")
case(_, 12, let date) where 27 < date:
        println("In winter vacation")
case(_, 1, let date) where 5 > date:
        println("In winter vacation")
case(year, month, date):
        println("\(year)-\(month)-\(date)")
}
```

と書かれていて、上の３つのcaseではlet dateとしているところを最後のcaseではdateとしているのはなぜなのでしょうか？
他の解説書も見て、whereのあるcaseは定数で宣言するのかなと考えたのですが、 この文では最初のcaseでwhereがないのにlet date です。

本に説明がないということは基本的なことなのだとは思うのですが、どなたかご説明いただけないでしょうか…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
case(year, month, date):
```

これは、

```
case let (year, month, date) :
```

の書き写し間違いではありませんか？

※この回答は、質問者さんからのReplyによって、随時加筆、変更する予定です。

Comment: おっしゃる通りでした…。簡単な見落としでお恥ずかしいです。ご回答いただきありがとうございました。

Comment: @seta333 この質問を削除なさっても、こちらはいっこうにかまいませんので……